# ImageBackground not showing an image

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and I was trying to do some crash course from internet. The guy added an ImageBackground to his app and it did work, however on my computer it doesn't. I tried to move it to different views also. The one more thing I was trying was to nest my view inside opening and closing ImageBackground tags and image was showing, but it was 100% height and content width.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.carContainer}>

      <ImageBackground
          source={require('./assets/images/ModelX.jpeg')}
          resizeMode="cover"
          styles={styles.image}/>

        <View style={styles.titles}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Model S</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Starting at $69,420</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  carContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  titles: {
    marginTop: '30%',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#5c5e62',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `resizeMode: cover` and `position: absolute` from your Stylesheet ? As far as I know, these are not usable here. ResizeMode is clarified as a prop of ImageBackground anyways.

Comment: There is the typo in the attribute name (styles={styles.image}).